# can ffmpeg process audio with nvidia cuda?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to process some audios as follow,

```
fmpeg -i input.wav -f wav -ar 16000 -ab 12800 -ac 1 output.wav
```

And I need to do it as fast as possible. So I try to use nvidia cuda to accelerate it.
I compile ffmpeg follow [this post](https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/#compiling-for-linux)
However, there isn't any example to use it with audio.

I try as follow, but it not work.

```
fmpeg -i input.wav -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -f wav -ar 16000 -ab 12800 -ac 1 output.wav
```

I find there is no any nvidia encoder and decoder specific for audio from [this post](https://pytorch.org/audio/main/hw_acceleration_tutorial.html#Configure-FFmpeg-build-with-Nvidia-CUDA-hardware-support)

```
Enabled decoders:
aac                     hevc                    rawvideo
av1                     mjpeg                   vc1
h263                    mpeg1video              vp8
h264                    mpeg2video              vp9
h264_cuvid              mpeg4

Enabled encoders:
h264_nvenc              libx264

Enabled hwaccels:
av1_nvdec               mpeg1_nvdec             vp8_nvdec
h264_nvdec              mpeg2_nvdec             vp9_nvdec
hevc_nvdec              mpeg4_nvdec             wmv3_nvdec
mjpeg_nvdec             vc1_nvdec
```

Comment: Audio conversion is already 'fast' [I can convert a ripped CD, call it an hour of input source, in about 30-40 seconds]. To be 'as fast as possible' you want more threads.

Comment: *there is no any nvidia encoder and decoder specific for audio* makes sense .. .since nvidia is in the business of *graphics* not *audio*

Comment: Besides, there's essentially no decoding process for wav (i.e. pcm stream with a header) input and no encoding process either when the output is also typical signed pcm as the input is. Actions that could be involved in your command are resampling, up/downmixing and truncation or dither (e.g. 24-bit to 16-bit). These processing actions are not normally done by a decoder or encoder. (For wav/pcm, decoder/encoder are often somewhat just a kind of metadata that signify the specification of an audio stream, which determines whether the aforementioned processing actions are required.)

Comment: Also, the maths here are probably not complexed enough to make offloading the computation to a (GP)GPU worthwhile, even *when* it is floating-point computation.

Comment: Thanks all. I have used multi-threads, and it's not enough, so I try to make it faster.@Tetsujin I am a newbie to ffmpeg, and your explanation is helpful to me.@TomYan

Comment: Encoding audio channels in FFmpeg is actually quite intense when doing many with a single command. It utilizes a single thread, and can be overloaded quite easily.